# Managing changes in use cases scenarios (EA - Enterprise Architect)

Tags: enterprise-architect, use-case, system-analysis

I'm using Enterprise Architect version 8.0.864 for a wide system analysis and design, and want to keep track of all the changes made in every element already registered.

Basically, my question in short is how can you see the changes made in use cases scenarios?

Using option "View" - "Other project tools" - "Audit View" (Mode: Advanced), you can see changes made to use case properties, but not changes made to use case scenarios. This changes are grouped in a folder named "Note Elements", but it is not clear at all, because changes appear under a folder icon with no description.

Is there a way to visualize scenarios changes grouped or to visualize all changes related to a specific use case (not only use case properties changes)?

Answer (score 0):

**For diagrams:**
Besides auditing, you can use Baselining as well. You'll find a description in the [EA user guide](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/projects_and_teams/tracking_changes.html)

Comparing to a baseline will give you a tree of elements and connectors, and for each of these a table of all properties where the changes are highlighted.

Note that this feature only works in certain editions of EA.

**For documents**, you can use "[Track changes](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/reporting/track_changes.html)".

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is that using baselining you can't see intermediate changes, that is, changes made between a baseline and the next one. And we want to see those changes as well.

Comment: Baselines are XMI based, so you can at least export each baseline to a separate file and then compare these individually using the "compare model to file" button.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible on Enterprise Architect v8

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought.